# How can I equalize the height of class boxes in a pgf-umlcd diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlcd, strut, uml

I have the following simple class diagram in pdf-umlcd:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{class}
        [text width=2cm]
        {Ah}
        {0,0}
        \operation{greet}
    \end{class}
    \begin{class}
        [text width=2cm]
        {Aj}
        {5,0}
        \operation{greet}
    \end{class}

    \unidirectionalAssociation{Ah}{knows}{}{Aj}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the boxes for both classes have different heights because the `j` in the second class name has a greater descent. This also causes the association between both classes not to be perfectly horizontal:

[image: Aj is higher than Ah]

How can I fix this? I already tried to:

- use a strut or phantom in the class name: Apparently not supported by tikz/pdf-umlcd ("Incomplete \iffalse").
- manually specify the height of each class by changing `[text width=2cm]` to `[text width=2cm,minimum height=10cm]`: Did not make any visual difference.

Do you know a way to equalize the height of class boxes? Ideally, there would be a patch that automatically inserts a strut (if my understanding of struts is correct) in each and every new class box.

Comment: `execute at begin node =\strut` or setting `text depth=0pt` could be a start. Unfortunately, the manual doesn't specify much about possible styles and how it implemented. Though, when one of your classes gets more functions or attributes they will line up even worse…

Comment: Thanks a lot! I posted my final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment, I added the following patch to my preamble:

```
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

% fix inconsistent class name box heights
\tikzset{
    umlcd style class/.append style={
        execute at begin node=\strut}}
% fix inconsistent operation/attribute row heights
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\pgfumlcd@operation}{\break}{\break\strut}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\pgfumlcd@attribute}{\break}{\break\strut}{}{}
```